# ndk-build Always returns LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

when build ndk with opencv i'm getting this error.
The files(abc.cpp and def.cpp) is present in jni folder, its name is correct, but getting this error always.

```
$ ndk-build
Android NDK: ERROR:/cygdrive/d/mySharedLibrary/jni/Android.mk:opencv_java: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file
Android NDK: Check that D:/Development/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/.
./libs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_java.so exists  or that its path is correct
/cygdrive/d/Development/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/prebuilt-library.mk:45:     *** 
Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
```

This is my Android.mk
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)

```
#OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=off
#OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=off
#OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED

override OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on

#$(info SHINU $(OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES))

include D:/Development/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk  

LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := abc.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  += def.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_MODULE     := abcd
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Folder Structure

```
D:\mySharedLibrary\jni
  Android.mk
  abc.cpp
  abc.h
  def.cpp
  def.h
```

**Edit:**
Problem Solved from here.

This was my Application.mk file

```
   APP_STL := gnustl_static
   APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
   APP_ABI := arm64-v8a
   APP_PLATFORM := android-8
```

me changed the 
    **APP_ABI := arm64-v8a**
    to 
    **APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a**

Comment: Why not **APP_ABI := all**?

Comment: One thing you need to know is ..open cv version below 3 will not support the 64 bit architecture devices so even you tried to compile to 64 bit it will not work.. you need to switch to opencv 3 or above

Comment: Ohh thank you @LinsLouis